# How do I configure the Azure Devops agent environment from a shell script?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Using builtin task "BatchScript@1", I can run a batch file found on the windows pipeline agent to modify the environment for the following tasks in the same job.

```
    jobs:
      - job
        steps:
          - task: BatchScript@1
            inputs:
              filename: /my/path/env.bat
              modifyEnvironment: true
```

I have the need to perform the same on a linux pipeline agent, using a shell script.

The builtin task "ShellScript@2" does not have a "modifyEnvironment" or similar option.

My shell script contains a multitude of "export some_var=value". I would like these env var to be accessible to the following tasks in the job.

Can this be achieved similarly to how I've done it for Windows?

Comment: "I would like these env var to be accessible to the following tasks in the job." Which tasks are you referring? do you mind sharing that

Comment: @Sibtain I have script tasks which will run other files which will grab environment variables, say for running Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not similar flag for Shell Script task. And if you want to set environment variables for subsequent tasks you should use command logging like

```
echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=TEST_VAR_2]Hello World!'
```

If you use just export it would be limited to this step.

For this script

```
TEST_VAR='Hello World!'
export TEST_VAR='Hello World!'
printenv | grep TEST_VAR

echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=TEST_VAR_2]Hello World!'
```

and this pipeline

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: ShellScript@2
  inputs:
    scriptPath: test.sh
- bash: |
    printenv | grep TEST_VAR
- bash: |
    printenv | grep TEST_VAR_2
```

I got:

[image]